# Including MIcrosoft Word document in QGIS layout?

Tags: qgis, layouts

How can I include a document and personal table from MSword to Qgis layout?

In Arcgis is possible include linked docs from .docx.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can see, there doesn't appear to be a straightforward way to insert a Word Document into a QGIS Layout.  However, QGIS does offer the option to add HTML, which might be a viable workaround.  You could save your Word Document as an HTML file and link it that way.  Of course, you might lose some formatting depending on the complexity of your Word document.

1. In the Layout menu, select add HTML...

[image]

2. Draw a frame.
3. In the settings for the HTML frame select your file.
4. There are settings to add frames if your doc spans multiple pages.
   [image]

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.  - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/100117)